# Thymeleaf and spring view resolver are working together when running on a server but not when running as spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

Configuration properties are:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

spring.thymeleaf.view-names:thymeleaf/*
```

Code to render **html** page is:

```
@GetMapping("/")
public String getIndex() {

    return "thymeleaf/index";
}
```

And to render **JSP** page code is, here home page is jsp.

```
@GetMapping("/form2")
public String getform2() {
    return "home";
}
```

Controller is getting called and this error is showing in the browser:

> Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for
>   /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Fri Oct 12 10:34:57 IST 2018 There was an unexpected error (type=Not
>   Found, status=404). No message available

If the question is not clear please let me know.
Thanks

Comment: Can you add application logs or error

Comment: I have edited the error, please check. Thanks

Comment: what did you type to browser when you saw this error?

Comment: The url to the controller that is http://localhost:8080/form2